# Calling async method in MVVM silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Facing some problem calling methods in Silverlight. 
Here's the scenario :--

My service agent contains the method which is calling a method in WCF service. The way i am calling is this :

```
   public void GetMethod(EventHandler<GetMethodCompletedEventArgs> callback)
    {
        _Proxy.GetMethodCompleted += callback;
        _Proxy.GetMethodAsync();
    }
```

I am calling this method in the View Model like this

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
ServiceAgent.GetMethod(inputVariable, new EventHandler<GetMethodCompletedEventArgs>(OnGetMethod_Completed));
}

void OnGetMethod_Completed(GetMethodCompletedEventArgs e)
{
int result = e.Result;
}
```

I have attached the method in the view model to a button in the UI.

Now the problem is, if i press the button first time everything works fine, if i press it twice the OnGetMethod_Completed() gets executed 2 time for one button click(i.e. 2nd button click), when i press it the third time it get executed 3 times and so on...
I really don't get it why this is happening, if anybody does then please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to unregister from the completed event on your OnGetMethod_Completed

```
void OnGetMethod_Completed(GetMethodCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  int result = e.Result;
  _Proxy.GetMethodCompleted  -= OnGetMethod_Completed
 }
```

Comment: FYI - it's not recommended to keep the proxy alive all the time, just keep the proxy factory(channel factory)

Answer (score 0):

For are async calls, you need to avoid subsequent calls before they occur, not at the end of a potentially lengthy process. Otherwise you can still quite happily trigger multiple events. While the results of all but the first will be ignored you are still sending data to/from the server (best avoided).

You actually want to simply disable the button or other GUI elements while processing is occurring. This is a perfect place to use a BusyIndicator, but simply binding the button's enabled state to the processing state is usually enough.